# Get CMake to print full name of target file

Tags: cmake

I have a C++ project built using CMake (which in turn uses GNU Make). Its output might look like (snipping other lines):

```
[ 12%] Building CXX object what/ever.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object another/one.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libfoo.so
```

Now, what I want to get on the output, is the exact full path of the `libfoo.so` target which got linked (possibly within a `CMakeFiles/` directory). But - I don't want to achieve this using GNU Make's verbosity settings. I want CMake itself to tell me where its targets are located. Is this possible?

Comment: If your intention is to extract the libraries out and copy it somewhere else, you should consider `install` your targets. (In fact, it's good practice to always `install` and export your targets)

Comment: @TerryTsao: No, that's not my intention... I actually want to be able to check on the specific `.so` file from outside of CMake and make, and/or make that file individually without all the rest of the targets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post build custom command.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET foo
                    POST_BUILD 
                    COMMAND echo "build dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} install dir ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
```

Comment: `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` is the top level dir of the build tree. The .so file may not be located there. Using a generator expression may be a better idea.

Comment: So, a custom command might be an appropriate mechanism, but the one you suggest doesn't do what I asked.

Comment: Effectively CMAKE_BINARY_DIR will work only in basic example but it was to show how to do without the verbose.I updated my answer.CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR seems to be what you want. It will give the right answer when using add_directory for example. otherwise you can look at LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.